# Modify the request body with a FiddlerScript rule

Tags: fiddler

I have several rules for testing that modify responses from a server, but can't figure out how to modify the body of a POST request with a FiddlerScript rule. `oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString()` sounds useful, but I can't see any way to *set* the request body after I've modified it.

Am I missing something, or is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var strBody=oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();                                                    
strBody=strBody.replace("foo","bar");
oSession.utilSetRequestBody(strBody);
```

Use this code to do that, in this sample foo is replaced by bar.